# C# Method Return

Tags: c#

I am writing a program which is about simple calculation in 3 different methods.
My code is working okay, but it doesn't grab the result back to Main.

Can anyone help me to find what is the problem for me?

Here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the first number\t");
    int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter the second number\t");
    int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    sum(number1, number2);
    difference(number1, number2);
    multiplies(number1, number2);            
}

public static int sum(int number1, int number2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sum is:");
    return number1 + number2;
}

public static int difference(int number1, int number2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("difference is:");
    return number1 - number2;
}

public static int multiplies(int number1, int number2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("multiplies:");
    return number1 - number2;
}
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You're doing nothing to output the results. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: other than what others have said,  1) don't do Console.Writeline inside your methods,  do it in the main, just do the sum / difference / multiples etc in the functions  2) Use standard C# naming conventions,  that means Methods start with a capital.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You have called the method from the main, that all process your inputs correctly and return the result to the main, but you have not received the values to a variable or displayed the return values from that method, display the result like the following:

```
Console.Write("{0} + {1} = {2}",number1,number2,sum(number1, number2));
console.Write("{0} - {1} = {2}",number1,number2,difference(number1, number2));
Console.Write("{0} * {1} = {2}",number1,number2,multiplies(number1, number2));
```

Let the inputs be `10` and `5` then the above code will displays the results as like the following:

```
10 + 5 = 15
10 - 5 = 5
10 * 5 = 50
```

or else use a variable to store the return value and then proceed with those values.

```
int sumResult = sum(number1, number2);
int diffResult = difference(number1, number2);
int mulResult = multiplies(number1, number2);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: If it really helps you, you can mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Change your main method as below.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write("Enter the first number\t");
        int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter the second number\t");
        int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(sum(number1, number2));
        Console.WriteLine(difference(number1, number2));
        Console.WriteLine(multiplies(number1, number2));


    }
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter the first number\t");
            int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the second number\t");
            int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            sum(number1, number2);
            difference(number1, number2);
            multiplies(number1, number2);
        }

        public static void sum(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sum is: {0}", number1 + number2));
        }

        public static void difference(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("difference is: {0}", number1 - number2));
        }
        public static void multiplies(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("multiplies : {0}", number1 * number2));
        }
```

Solution 2 :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter the first number\t");
            int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the second number\t");
            int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(sum(number1, number2));
            Console.WriteLine(difference(number1, number2));
            Console.WriteLine(multiplies(number1, number2));

        }

        public static int sum(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sum is:");
            return number1 + number2;
        }

        public static int difference(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("difference is:");
            return number1 - number2;
        }
        public static int multiplies(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("multiplies:");
            return number1 * number2;
        }
```

The issue is that you are not printing the result to the console.

Comment: Wow... amazing.. Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following way:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the first number\t");
            int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the second number\t");
            int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int result1=sum(number1, number2);
            Console.WriteLine(result1);
            int result2=difference(number1, number2);
            Console.WriteLine(result2);
            int result3=multiplies(number1, number2);
            Console.WriteLine(result3);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public  static int sum(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sum is:");
            return number1 + number2;
        }

        public static int difference(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("difference is:");
            return number1 - number2;
        }
        public static int multiplies(int number1, int number2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("multiplies:");
            return number1*number2;
        }
```

Comment: Easy to check!! :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Rachel Kim,if it is useful to you.please accept me as an answer